# Configure hibernate to connect to database via JNDI Datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jndi, connection-pooling

Hi all
I'm using Hibernate+Struts2+Tomcat6+Mysql as my J2EE framework. I've been using hibernate's built-in connection pooling mechanism but it turned out to be problematic where mysql closes it's connections after 8 hours. Anyway I googled around a little bit and found that I should get my connections through JNDI datasource but I couldn't reach a good and complete tutorial on this. What steps should I take to do so? please provide me enough of details, I'm kinda new on this.
here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/hposg?characterEncoding=UTF-8
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">25</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" >3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

      <!-- Mapping files -->

      <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Player.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Game.hbm.xml"/>
      ...

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I also tried this but it didn't work out:
Creating a context.xml in WebContent/META-INF containing:

```
<Context path="" docBase="../RSGames" debug="0" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/RSGames" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         username="root"
         password=""
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hposg?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
         maxActive="15"
         maxIdle="7"
         validationQuery="Select 1" />
</Context>
```

putting this in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/RSGames</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.Datasource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and modifying hibernate config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
  ...
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/RSGames</property>
  ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

as I mentioned before, it doesn't get connected to database this way. any ideas?

[EDIT]
When I execute the app I get this exception:

```
Mar 16, 2011 12:29:13 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1f18cbe -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Mar 16, 2011 12:29:13 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@14f1726 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Mar 16, 2011 12:29:13 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@cad437 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
29994 [http-8081-3] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
    at com.hposg.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    at com.hposg.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    at com.hposg.login.LoginFactory.doLogin(LoginFactory.java:25)
    at com.hposg.controller.struts.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app? Do you get an exception? Do you get direct access to the DB?

Comment: Well I get an exception you can see the stacktrace above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently, you did it right. But here is a list of things you'll need with examples from a working application:

1) A context.xml file in META-INF, specifying your data source:

```
<Context>
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/DsWebAppDB" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        username="sa" 
        password="" 
        driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:h2:mem:target/test/db/h2/hibernate" 
        maxActive="8" 
        maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

2) web.xml which tells the container that you are using this resource:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/DsWebAppDB</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

3) Hibernate configuration which consumes the data source. In this case, it's a `persistence.xml`, but it's similar in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="dswebapp">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DsWebAppDB"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I exactly copied your codes and made a few minor changes. here is the code in context.xml:
`<Context>
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/hposg" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        username="root" 
        password="123456" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hposg?characterEncoding=UTF-8" 
        maxActive="8" 
        maxIdle="4"/>`

Comment: and this is the hibernate config: 
`<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/hposg</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>`

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that you are using C3P0. Remove all mentions to C3P0 from hibernate.cfg.xml . Also, make sure you don't have a hibernate.properties in your classpath.

Comment: yeah right, I've been doing sth really silly in there using both c3p0 and JNDI. I removed all the c3p0 configurations and it's working fine now. necessary to mention for people who might struggle with this in the future that you need to copy mysql-connector-java.jar to your tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: @Erick Yeah, he said it's working fine now. Well at least it was working fine in 2011, I can't really say if it's still working fine.

Comment: why is using C3PO and JNDI silly? don't they both do different things? doesn't JNDI provide a pool for the `javax.sql.Datasource` object and C3PO pools the connections received from the `javax.sql.Datasource` object?

Comment: @jpkrohling, under the psersistence.xml isn't it better to use j2ee built in JPA?

Answer (score 10):

### **Tomcat-7 JNDI configuration:**

### Steps:

1. Open the *server.xml* in the *tomcat-dir/conf*
2. Add below `<Resource>` tag with your DB details inside `<GlobalNamingResources>`

```html
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
          global="jdbc/mydb"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
          username="root"
          password=""
          maxActive="10"
          maxIdle="10"
          minIdle="5"
          maxWait="10000"/>
```

3. Save the *server.xml* file
4. Open the *context.xml* in the *tomcat-dir/conf*
5. Add the below `<ResourceLink>` inside the `<Context>` tag.

```html
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" 
              global="jdbc/mydb"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

6. Save the *context.xml*
7. Open the *hibernate-cfg.xml* file and add and remove below properties.

```html
Adding:
-------
<property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</property>

Removing:
--------
<!--<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property> -->
<!--<property name="connection.username">root</property> -->
<!--<property name="connection.password"></property> -->
```

8. Save the file and put latest .WAR file in tomcat.
9. Restart the tomcat. the DB connection will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in my IBM Websphere with c3p0 jar files. I have Oracle 10g database. I simply added the oraclejdbc.jar files in the Application server JVM in IBM Classpath using Websphere Console and the error was resolved.

The oraclejdbc.jar should be set with your C3P0 jar files in your Server Class path whatever it be tomcat, glassfish of IBM.

Comment: Pankaj, try to re-word your answer so it doesn't start with "I am getting the same error" - people will otherwise tend to consider your answer for an *This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment.*

Answer (score 0):

Inside applicationContext.xml file of a maven Hibernet web app project below settings worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
```

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
                 jndi-name="Give_DataSource_Path_From_Your_Server"
                 expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Hope It will help someone.Thanks!