# Frontend for Hibernate and SQL 2008 Connection through JSP or JS

Tags: javascript, hibernate, jsp, jndi

I am working on application which uses `GWT` as front end and `Hibernate 4.0` Framework. I am using **SQL 2008 (R2).** My application is purely DB Driven. And the application would get launch at multiple portals simultaneously with different DB. Right now, the problem which I am facing is, I have to deploy as many wars as many DBs are there for each Portal. Is there any way with Hibernate to make it configurable? Means After loading my Homepage after entering **db name, db user_name and db password** it gets connected to the DB.

I would also bring you notice that my **Homepage** gets loaded in `JSP`. And after login it is calling **GWT Entrypoint**.

Comment: Please don't downvote it. As it is very much important for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use JNDI bound data sources?

Comment: Can you give me a piece of code ? As I have not used it.

Comment: What app server are you using to deploy your wars?

Comment: I am using JBoss 7 to deploy war.

Comment: So, you want to have one single WAR which you can deploy on each portal, and the choice to which DB the application connects depends on the user input, right? Like a kind of database administration tool?

Comment: yes you got it right !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @ToddMurray in the comments, you should use a configurable JNDI dataSource. It's the preferred way to go with containers like JBoss. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303671/configure-hibernate-to-connect-to-database-via-jndi-datasource) for a config example.

Another way to go is with Hibernate properties: read the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc).