# Design for Hibernate external config for app server and local Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, configuration

I have found many posts on here about using Spring to externalize the Hibernate settings so it's not in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` config file. However, my question revolves around having a development environment that uses Eclipse and then deploying the generated WAR file out on a separate server.

I am currently using Eclipse Luna and deploying my Spring MVC web application to a local install of Tomcat 8. The `hibernate.cfg.xml` file currently resides in the **resources** folder. When I deploy it locally, it works great. However, the config uses my personal login credentials, which isn't good to have on the server for everyone to see.

What I need is to figure out a design to have the application work locally and when I deploy on the server.

I was thinking about creating a folder called **conf** and placing the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in here and through the Eclipse classpath (Debug As configuration...) define it as a folder. That should allow the local version to still read in the proper files and work. But I am stuck on how to setup the server side of this. Since we just drop in the WAR file, it will auto deploy. I can use a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, but that will throw errors on my local copy.

The only other thing I can think of is to create a process where I create the folder for the application, unpack the WAR file into this folder each time minus the **conf** folder. And only update the **conf** folder on the server.

Is this a good design or is there a better way? I appreciate all the help and guidance on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work and figured I would share how I did it

I went ahead and created the "conf" folder in the root folder. In here I placed a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, `log4j.properties` and `messages.properties` file. I then created a subfolder called "db" and placed `db.properties` file in there.

So the structure is:

```
ApplicationName
--> conf
    --> db
        db.properties
    hibernate.cfg.xml
    log4j.properties
    messages.properties
```

**db.properties**

In this file, I placed the hibernate connection information (and other information)

```
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
db.default_schema=<schema>

hibernate.session_context=thread
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=20
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=false

hibernate.c3p0.min_size=1
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=3000
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=300
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1 from DUAL

# DEV
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>

# Need to be changed
db.username=<username>
db.password=<password>
```

The **hibernate.cfg.xml** file just had the Entity mappings in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Entity mapping -->
        <mapping class="com.mine.Entity1"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.mine.Entity2"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In the **HibernateUtil.java** file, I added the following lines:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();

PropertyResourceBundle prop = (PropertyResourceBundle) ResourceBundle.getBundle("db/db");

// Basic connection information
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", prop.getString("db.username"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", prop.getString("db.password"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", prop.getString("db.url"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", prop.getString("db.driver"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", prop.getString("db.dialect"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", prop.getString("db.default_schema"));

configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", prop.getString("hibernate.session_context"));

// Handling SQL statements in the logs
configuration.setProperty("show_sql", prop.getString("hibernate.show_sql"));
configuration.setProperty("format_sql", prop.getString("hibernate.format_sql"));
configuration.setProperty("use_sql_comments", prop.getString("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));

// C3P0 Settings
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.min_size"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.max_size"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.timeout"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", prop.getString("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery"));
```

In the ***-servlet.xml** file:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
            <value>classpath:db/db.properties</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>  
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60"/> 
</bean>
```

In Eclipse, when I go to run the application, I must first go to "Debug As... => Debug Configuration...". Under Classpath, I add the **conf** folder under the user entries section.

That's it for Eclipse. When it runs, it will pull in the configs from the **conf** folder and work properly.

**TOMCAT**

To have this run on the server, I first created a folder to store the contents of **conf**. I created the folder `/app/properties`. I checked out the project from SVN and copied the contents of the **conf** folder into the newly created folder.

Lastly, I went into `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties` and added the new folder into the classpath by adding it to the `shared.loader` property.

That's it! When the WAR is deployed, it pulls the information from the `/app/properties` location and the application works.

Any more information needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that. First you need to use JNDI to access the datasource. There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303671/configure-hibernate-to-connect-to-database-via-jndi-datasource) [examples](http://www.journaldev.com/2905/hibernate-tomcat-jndi-datasource-example-tutorial) how to that and you can probably find more.

One of the thing that need to be done is to [configure](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) datasource as resource in tomcat context. And the trick is to have [different context configurations](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) for your local deployment from eclipse and on production.
In local deployment pack `context.xml` as part of the war in `META-INF` folder but in production deployment create `context.xml` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` which would override `context.xml` supplied in war.

Another option is to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with option to override settings from environment variables. This will require that you specify database credentials in environment variables in tomcat server launch configuration.