# Set a default schema for Hibernate via JNDI reference

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, websphere, jndi

I use Spring 4, Hibernate 4 and WebSphere 8.5.7. Having such a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION", schema = "NEW_SCHEMA")
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_NEW")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_NEW", schema = "NEW_SCHEMA", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NEW", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
```

I want to have an ability to change a schema in the @Table signature via JNDI name. I expect to get something like this:

```
@Table(name = "APPLICATION", schema = "${schema.jndi}")
```

Assuming that `${schema.jndi}` will be provided by Websphere.

Another words, in business context, the task looks as follows. I need to exclude any mention of the schema in a whole project code (Java, xml, props). And make it possible changing a schema directly from WebShpere.

What is the simplest way to implement a solution?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to configure a schema for the entire application (for every entity) , you can do that in your Hibernate configuraton file (typically WAS will have a reference to this config file)

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">myschema</property>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It will help to exclude any mention of the schema in a Java code. But is it possible to avoid it's usage in the whole project code?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303671/configure-hibernate-to-connect-to-database-via-jndi-datasource

Answer (score 0):

IBM WebSphere Application Server provides data source configuration which lets you to set your default schema.
Check below via left side Menu bar:

> Resources -> Data sources -> YOUR DataSource -> Additional Properties -> Custom Properties

Find ***'currentSchema'*** property and change its value to your desired schema. Remember to save new configuration and test the connection to ensure the node synchronization in case of clustered environment.
Also it might need to restart your application server in order to see new changes.

In this case there is no need to mention schema name in whole of your project codes.